# where clause in query that contain all dates in range

Tags: mysql

i need to fill missing dates with last values available, so i am going on first step to get query with all dates including missing one on daily table. I know there a lot of question about fill missing dates, but here i need where clause on that query. 
People usually suggest to make separate table with all dates in, and then use left join with other table to get all dates, and for values that are missing you get NULL which is fine.

So i created that table and called it calendar, and tried this query:

```
SELECT d.`date`, s.`item`, s.state 
FROM calendar d LEFT JOIN daily_states s
ON d.`date` = s.`date`
WHERE s.`item` = 'item1'
ORDER BY s.`date` ASC;
```

Hoping i get result(example1):

```
Date        | Item  | State

2013-05-01    item1   state1
2013-05-02    item1   state1
2013-05-03    NULL    NULL
2013-05-04    item1   state3
2013-05-05    NULL    NULL
2013-05-06    item1   state3
2013-05-07    item1   state1
```

where i am sure only NULL values in item is actually item1 but date is missing from right table. That way i can later fill missing item and state values with previous states and end with this result(example2):

```
2013-05-01    item1   state1
2013-05-02    item1   state1
2013-05-03    item1   state1
2013-05-04    item1   state3
2013-05-05    item1   state3
2013-05-06    item1   state3
2013-05-07    item1   state1
```

But because of WHERE clause, i get this(result):

```
2013-05-01    item1   state1
2013-05-02    item1   state1
2013-05-04    item1   state3
2013-05-06    item1   state3
2013-05-07    item1   state1
```

so i still dont have missing dates. How to get result as in example1? 
Btw i made [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54e913/6) with examples.
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

retrieve also the NULL values :

add an

```
OR s.item IS NULL
```

in your `where` clause

```
SELECT d.`date`, s.`item`, s.state 
FROM calendar d LEFT JOIN daily_states s
ON d.`date` = s.`date`
WHERE s.`item` = 'item1' OR s.item IS NULL
ORDER BY d.`date` ASC;
```

by the way I would order by `d.date`, not `s.date` (which may be null)

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54e913/9)